Content-type Negotiation
In Content-type Negotiation config
I am trying to register more than one configuration to deal with other types of result
 install(ContentNegotiation) {
            register(ContentType.Application.SirenJson, SirenJsonConverter())
            register(ContentType.Application.ProblemJson, ProblemConverter())
            json()
        }

But it just register the first one, and I can't find any documentation to validate if I can or not do this

seems correct, what issue are you facing? Any error?

when my server response with a contentType of kind ProblemJson the result is this
In response from http://***/***
23:46:08.027  W  Response status 4**
23:46:08.027  W  Response header **
23:46:08.027  W  Request header Accept: *
23:46:08.027  W
23:46:08.028  W  You can read how to resolve NoTransformationFoundException at FAQ:  blablabla

plz update the question, unable to understand the comment
